# Getting empty array trying to parse xml with attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am attempting to parse an xml file with attributes, and keep getting an empty array.  Here is a sample of the xml, which is parsed as a simplexml_load_string:

```
     <NumberOfOfferListings>
    <OfferListingCount condition="Any">61</OfferListingCount>
    <OfferListingCount condition="Used">45</OfferListingCount>
    <OfferListingCount condition="New">16</OfferListingCount>
  </NumberOfOfferListings>
```

Here is the php code that I am using

```
$priceComp_xml = amazonCompPrice_xml($asin);
$compPricing = $priceComp_xml->xpath('OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]');
```

amazonCompPrice($asin) is the parsed xml file based on the ASIN value.

I need to extract just:

```
<OfferListingCount condition="Any">61</OfferListingCount>
```

I have looked at many examples on here to get to this point, and it looks like what I have is correct, just returns an empty array when I use either print_r($compPricing) or var_dump.
How do I fix this to get the information that I need??
I can upload any more snippets of code that will help resolve this issue.

Comment: Unless the XML you quoted is the entire document, your XPath query is not quite right. It only looks for an `<OffsetListingCount>` which is a child (c.f, descendant) of whatever `$priceComp_xml` holds. The simplest change would be to use `//OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]`

Comment: I am a little confused, should it look like this then:$compPricing = $priceComp_xml->xpath('//OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two separate issues at play here.

#### The XPath

Your XPath, `OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]`, will only return matching `<OfferListingCount>` elements which are children of the element held in `$priceComp_xml`. It will not match *descendant* elements which are grand-children, or further down the tree.

So, it needs to be amended to match the `<OfferListingCount>` element(s).  A quick fix usually to employ the shorthand `//` (short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`), like `//OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]`.

#### Namespaces

Your question did not mention this, but some digging uncovered that the XML document probably has a default namespace applied to it. This can be recognised by looking at the document element for `xmlns="…"`.  When using XPath, this namespace needs to be [registered](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace) and used when querying.

```
$priceComp_xml->registerXPathNamespace('products', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01');
$compPricing = $priceComp_xml->xpath('//products:OfferListingCount[@condition="Any"]');
```

Finally, remember that `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` returns an *array*, so your matching `<offerListingCount>` element will be available as `$compPricing[0]`.

```
$count = (int) $compPricing[0];
```

Comment: Do I need this whole line <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"> or just the part that you posted?

Comment: Just the part I posted, the code registers a `products` prefix for the namespace URI `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01`.  This prefix can then be used in the query.

Comment: Registering the namespace seems to have done the trick!  Thank You very much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. A *huge* number of people stumble over that particular issue.